# Select the same column multiple times with MySQL

Tags: mysql, sql, select

Assuming I have something like this :

MySQL Table

```
Date     | Name    |    Val
22/11    | a       |    1
22/11    | b       |    2
22/11    | a       |    3
22/11    | a       |    4
23/11    | b       |    1
23/11    | a       |    2
23/11    | a       |    3
23/11    | a       |    5
```

I need a query to have on one column the sum of the values for each day when Name = 'a' and an other column for the sum of all the values (for each day too).

With my example, the result would be something like this :

```
Date    | a.Total  |    Total
22/11   | 8        |    10
23/11   | 10       |    11
```

I tried something like this :

```
SELECT date, SUM(Val) AS a.Total, SUM(Val) AS Total FROM tbl1 Where Name = 'a'
```

The point is that I need to specify a WHERE clause to get the "a.total" values (WHERE Name = 'a') but I don't want it to be apply to get the total.
I also tried queries with Left Join but it didn't work.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Whenever you use an aggregate function (e.g., `SUM`) you will most likely need a `GROUP BY` clause (unless you are looking for a single value).  Your first column should should be `SUM(IF(NAME='A',Val,0))` or a `CASE` (the point being put a decision making function in it)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `GROUP BY` and `CASE` inside of the first `SUM()`

```
SELECT date, 
SUM( CASE WHEN Name='a'
          THEN Val
          ELSE 0
     END) AS a_Total, 
SUM(Val) AS Total 

FROM tbl1 
GROUP BY `Date`
```

<kbd>[SQLFiddle demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/e0923/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 1):

This is a type of problem called cross-tabbing (see https://www.simple-talk.com/sql/t-sql-programming/creating-cross-tab-queries-and-pivot-tables-in-sql/)

What you're after is the use of a `CASE` statement to allow you to sum values only when a condition is met.

```
SELECT date, SUM(CASE WHEN Name='a' then Val end) AS a.Total, SUM(Val) AS Total FROM tbl1 GROUP BY date
```

Comment: Thank you very much too ! I chose valex's answer because of the demo but your help is appreciated